# Show 0 instead of empty cell in PivotTable through vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do I programmatically do the following:

Change empty cells to 0 in a pivottable.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PivotTable has a NullString property:

```
activesheet.pivottables(1).nullstring = "0"
```

for example.